How to prevent VS Code from popping up when ssh disconnects (ubuntu)
If my remote-ssh session disconnects while I have another window open, VS Code will pop up with a warning about the session having disconnected. I don't want this to pop up. A notification would be fine

Have you tried adding a ridiculously high timeout at Remote.SSH: Connect Timeout or setting this Remote.SSH: Max Reconnection Attempts or maybe this setting Window: Dialog Style and setting it to custom, not sure what custom does TBH.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
